# Angular dynamic formArray can't find the controls

Tags: angular, forms, angular8, formarray, dynamic-forms

I have troubles building a dynamic form with the help of the FormArray, i'm trying to build a form based on an array that contains Object describing a row of a database. The goal is to show the user every row that he selected with their current values letting the user modify them and send them back.

So everything need to be modular because i don't know the number of rows that he selected neither the number of columns of the table, and i still need to be able to retreive the new data.

I managed to do something that should work but i still have an error :

*`Error : Cannot find control with name: 'XXXXX'`*

I feel like it might be a story of lifeCycleHook and the html is somehow executing before the controls are set up in the typescript.

I first created a formArray named modifyForm and a formBuilder

```
 modifyForm: FormArray;

 constructor private fb: FormBuilder){}
```

and then in my ngOnInit function i created a loop that fill the modifyForm with the right controls and also fill the externalArray that the HTML will use to create the user interface.

Typescript :

```
ngOnInit() {


    let internalObjects = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedRows.length; i++) {
      const row = this.selectedRows[i];
      internalObjects = {}

      for (let y = 0; y < Object.keys(row).length; y++) {
        const key = Object.keys(row)[y];
        const value = Object.values(row)[y];

        if (key !== "#") {
          this.modifyForm.push(this.fb.control(i + key))
          internalObjects[key] = value;
        }
      }
      this.externalArray.push(internalObjects)
    }
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="modifyForm">
        <div *ngFor="let object of externalArray; let item = index ">
                <div *ngFor="let value of object | keyvalue">
                    <mat-form-field>
                       <input matInput [formControlName]='item+value.key' [value]='value.value'>
                    </mat-form-field>
               </div>
         </div>
</form>
```

What's weird is that at the end of the ngOnInit function i console Log the controls it seems to created with the proper values and it still say that it can't find them.

Typescript loops :

```
   for (const control of this.modifyForm.controls) {
      console.log(control.value)
    }
```

The result :

[image: 1]

I know it's a lot to digest, i tried to give as many informations as i could and i hope it's not too hard to read. I've been searching for days and i'm still stuck here. Thanks to anyone who could help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not binding to your form array correctly. With form groups and form arrays you bind to the key. In the case of form arrays, this is the index.

```
this.modifyForm.push(this.fb.control(i + key))
```

This is adding a form control with the value `i + key` at the next available index in the form array.

In your HTML you should bind to the index instead of the value. You shouldn't need to manually set the `[value]` - that comes from the form binding.

```
<input matInput [formControlName]='item' />
```

Where `item` is the current index in the form array as defined in `*ngFor`

#### Binding to complex objects

If you want to create an array of multiple form controls, you would set up an array of form groups and your HTML directives would reflect your form structure.

```js
const formGroups: FormGroup[] = myArray.map(x => new FormGroup({
  prop1: new FormControl(x.prop1),
  prop2: new FormControl(x.prop2)
}));
this.form = new FormArray(formGroups);
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"> <!-- <<< bind to the ith form array entry -->
    <input formControlName="prop1" />
    <input formControlName="prop2" />
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Binding to unknown properties

If you don't know what your object properties are, you can create your form from your object keys.

```js
this.form = new FormArray(this.selectedRows.map(row => {
  const formGroup = new FormGroup({});
  Object.keys(row).forEach(key => { // <-- use Object.keys to iterate the object
    formGroup.addControl(key, new FormControl(row[key]));
  });
  return formGroup;
}));
```

And generate your HTML from the object keys

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let row of selectedRows;let i = index">                
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <!-- use the keyvalue pipe to iterate the key/value pairs of the object -->
      <span *ngFor="let keyvalue of row | keyvalue">
        <input [formControlName]="keyvalue.key" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1jd6x

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer Kurt !
First as i cleaned the code i missed the pipe on the 1st loop, sorry for this.
I thought i needed the controls to all be different to differentiate them afterward when i'll read the data, if i only put the "item" each loop of the externalArray will create the same controlName, no? 
When i try to put the item only and give up the [value] i have the key name as the value on the input like : TEST1 : TEST1 so maybe i do wrong somewhere else?
I do think i have a 1-1 mapping because when i log it i always have as much controls as the inputs on the screen

Comment: It's enough just to set the formControlName to the index of the array. https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-template-jsdsgb

Comment: I can't change my latest comment idk why but here is the right comment : 
Hello again Kurt. 
I tried to take it slow and build the whole thing again with your methodology but i still can't get it to work like i want. I made a stackblitz to show the problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viuopq
 i have these error : Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> 0'

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here. Are you saying you want to create a 2D array of form controls? You can't just set the value of a form control to be an array and expect it to work for a text box.

Comment: That's what i don't get, i have 2 for loop here, one to retrieve the array, and one to iterate over it. But somehow the value is still an array. 

The "selectedRows" array is one that i can't know the size and object shape inside it beforehand because it's user selection based. I need to create a form with these data and be abble to retreive the data entered by the user afterward. 

i might've gone the wrong way ?

Comment: Can you create a static form as a mockup of what you want, with an example of the data it should be created from. In your stackblitz I see an array (of unknown length) of objects (of known structure). My assumption would be that for for your demo you want 3 rows of 3 controls. Each row would have the controls: `test1`, `test2`, `test3`.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i want !
I updated only the html of the stackblitz to represent what i want it to show the user : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viuopq

Comment: In that case you want an array of form groups. Each form group has a form control for the property you want to create an input for. It's simple once you realise what you need to do. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5nmpd

Comment: Thank god you exist ! I'm giving it a try, thanks again Kurt !

Comment: I feel really bad but i just can't figure it out for the past 2 hours, your example is perfect except for the fact that i also need to populate the FormGroup, in the map function, with dynamic formControl Names. 

I have test1,test2 and test3 in the example, but it might be anything, and most importantly it can vary in number as well. I'm trying to find a way of looping in the function but it's not possible and the FormGroup structure is hard to handle in my opinion.

I'm really sorry to bother you again, i hope i explained my problem right

Comment: Added a new section to my answer. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1jd6x Now it's just a case of iterating over the object's properties and using the property names as the form group keys